# Can't call onData inside listener

Tags: dart

I have very small app:

```
main() async
 {
  Stream stream = Stream.fromIterable([1,2,3,4]);

  stream.listen(
    (d) { print(d); },
    onDone: () { print("all done"); }
  );
 }
```

I can't understand why I can't call `onData` in the same manner as `onDone` like:

```
onData: (d) { print(d); }
```

[Docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onData` parameter to `listen` is a *positional parameter*, and the `onDone` parameter is a *named parameter*. All parameters are one or the other, and it determines how you pass an argument for that parameter.

To pass an argument for a named parameter, you must use the name, so you write `onDone: () { ... }`.

To pass an argument for a positional parameter, you just write the value. You cannot use the name.

So, to call `listen` with both, you write:

```
stream.listen(
    (data) { handleData(...); },
    onDone: () { handleDone(...); }
);
```

which passes one positional argument and one named arugment with the name `onDone`.

Comment: thanks! But can I do something like this: `stream.listen.then((d) { print(d) } );`

Comment: No. I am not sure what you are *trying* to do, but that code definitely does not work. The `listen` is a method, and you need to call it to use it. It does not have a `then` method.